# Cypher query that stops after a specific condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher.  I have a large graph of people related by friendship and I would like to get all of the paths starting from 1 person but stopping at a friend from another state.  I need to show the first friend from the other state but none of his/her friends.  Basically, I want the path to end when it find a node who's related friend is not from the specified state.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Jack {st:'MI'}<-[Friend]-Jill {st:'MI'}<-[Friend]-John {st:'OH'}<-[Friend]-Tim {st:'OH'}
```

Query should only return Jack, Jill and John.  Not Tim.

Edit/Addition

```
John <-[Friend]-Joan {st:'MI'}
```

Joan should also not be returned in the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this. Match all of the friend that are in the same state and then take the end of that path and match all of the friends next to the end that are from a different state.

```
MATCH path=(start:Person {name: 'Jack'})<-[:FRIEND*]-(end:Person)
WHERE end.st = start.st
AND all(p in nodes(path) where p.st = start.st)
WITH path, end
RETURN nodes(path), [(end)<-[:FRIEND]-(other:Person) WHERE other.st <> end.st | other]  as other_state
```

This query will only return the rows where there are `other_state` nodes.

```
MATCH path=(start:Person {name: 'Joe'})<-[:FRIEND*..10]-(end:Person)
WHERE end.st = start.st
AND all(p in nodes(path) where p.st = start.st)
WITH nodes(path) as same_state, [(end)<-[:FRIEND]-(other:Person) WHERE other.st <> end.st | other]  as other_state
WHERE size(other_state) > 0
RETURN same_state, other_state
```

Changed so would accommodate the John, Joan and Tim use case

```
MATCH path=(start:Person {name: 'John'})-[:FRIEND*0..]-(end:Person)
WHERE end.st = start.st
AND all(p in nodes(path) where p.st = start.st)
WITH nodes(path) as same_state, [(end)-[:FRIEND]-(other:Person) WHERE other.st <> end.st | other]  as other_state
WHERE size(other_state) > 0
RETURN same_state, other_state
```

Comment: That works, but there is a twist.  If Joan is a friend of John's from MI - she also shouldn't show.  I'll update the data set to be more clear.  Sorry I missed that.

Comment: The second query works for Jack, but if I start with John, I want to get Joan and Tim back.  It doesn't return anything for John.  This may be harder than I thought.

Comment: Added a new query. Had to change a few things. Added capacity for a path that just contains a single node and took out the directedness in the relationships.

Comment: That works for John, but it still returns Joan if you start with Jack.  I do appreciate your input on this.  Thank you.

Comment: sorry, missed that, i added an update to accommodate that